# What are XCB equivalents of XIfEvent(), XMaskEvenf(), XWindowEvent(), XCheckTypedEvent(), etc

Tags: event-handling, x11, xcb

Xlib offers a series of functions which return specific events, like `XIfEvent()`, `XMaskEvent()`, `XWindowEvent()`, `XCheckTypedEvent()` (and their "Check" versions) ...

How about for XCB? Is there any way to get only specific events in the event queue?

`xcb_wait_for_special_event()` seems to be one of such functions, but there is no detailed manual, so I don't know how to use it.

I tried to read source codes of xlib and xcb, but it was beyond my capacity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With libxcb, there is no "fancy event queue management". You'll have to call `xcb_poll_for_event()` in a loop yourself and put events in your own event queue. Then you can handle events in that queue in whatever order you want, prioritising some events, if you want.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. XCB seems less convenient than Xlib, but I think it gives me a chance to know more about X11 and technical details.

Comment: Well... personally, I never needed these fancy functions. The most complicated that I needed was "only handle the last MotionNotify event in the queue and ignore earlier ones". For that, I had a variable `xcb_generic_event_t *motion = NULL;` before my loop. Each new motion notify event was not handled, but saved in this function. Other events were handled immediately. After the loop, if there was a motion notify event, it was handled. I think the resulting code is more readable than the same with XLib's function, but basically it comes down to "matter of taste", I guess.

Comment: Your code will be very readable. I haven't experienced such a situation (handle only the last MotionNotify event), so your sample was interesting for me.

Comment: What are you using these Xlib functions for? Or was this question just out of general curiousness?

Comment: I want to make a simple window manager. Originally I was writing codes with Xlib, but recently I switched to XCB.